# how do i go about committing one file using git?

Tags: git, commit

when i enter "git status" i see something like:

```
C:\cygwin\home\GIT\webapps>git status
# On branch webapp_633
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       renamed:    dir/another_dir/then_another_dir/dir_AGAIN/file.jsp -> dir/another_dir/then_another_dir/dir_AGAIN2/file.jsp
#       renamed:    dir/another_dir/then_another_dir/dir_AGAIN/file2.jsp -> dir/another_dir/then_another_dir/dir_AGAIN2/file2.jsp
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       dir/another_dir/then_another_dir/target
#       dir/dir/another_dir/then_another_dir/target
#       dir/dir/dir/another_dir/then_another_dir/target
#       dir/dir/dir/dir/another_dir/then_another_dir/target
#       dir/dir/another_dir/then_another_dir/dir/target
```

normally i just use "git commit -m "message"" to commit all the files, but here i only renamed 2 files, i looked in the /target folders and theres nothing that needs to be committed.

any help?

Comment: What are you trying to commit?

Comment: Using `git commit -a` or any other "global" git commit command is very bad practice. Just use `git add` to add the relevant files. Here, the changes you want are already in the index (`Changes to be commited`), so just issue a `git commit`.

Comment: @Simon im trying to commit the 2 jsp files, it seems there are iml/random files in the target folders which i dont want to commit..

Comment: @fge so if i just use git commit, it will only commit the 2 jsp files? or will it commit everything?

Comment: If you mean the untracked files, then they won't be committed if you do a 'git commit -m "blah"'

Comment: @JoeChen it will just commit the two files, as I said. This is what the index is all about. You should really go and read about it, it is an essential concept to grasp when working with git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The untracked files won't be committed, so you can just do:

```
git commit -m "message"
```

If you need to commit the untracked files, you will first need to add them with git add first.

I recommend http://think-like-a-git.net/

Comment: @JoeChen Highly recommend it!

Comment: one more question, what is an easy way to add files? lets say i have a file in "dir/dir/dir/dir/file.jsp" is there a way to add it without typing the whole path?

Comment: `git add` is recursive. As long as there are no other files that have been changed or are new, you can use `git add` any part of the path.

Comment: imho the best approach is to use .gitignore and .git/info/excludes so that any "junk" files (built objects/classes/executables, core dumps, editor backups) are ignored, and then you can safely do "git add ." to add all new files. or even "git add -A ." to say "push everything I've done to staging, including adding/deleting/moving files".